# Records created with a previously deleted ID generates an uncaught error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase, emberfire

In my application, I have what I think is a fairly standard `User` model, whose IDs are based on the authenticated users' `fbRef.getAuth().uid` value (which in my case is assigned by the Anonymous authentication provider). I have a global users which dynamically updates as users authenticate/unauthenticate, that is populated using a basic `this.store.find('user')` call.

The problem arises when a user signs out, and then re-authenticates/signs in with the same auth uid. I recieve the following error in the consoles of the other currently connected browsers:

> Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on  while in state root.deleted.uncommitted.

(note however, that the user/browser that did the signing out/re-logging in receives no error)

Is there anything else I need to do in this scenario to make sure that records automatically deleted by emberfire are fully committed in each connected client's cached store, or is this a limitation of some sort?

For reference, here is how I am creating the records when a user signs in:

```
var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {
    id: fbRef.getAuth().uid,
    nickname: nickname,
    joinedAt: new Date()
});

user.save();
```

And when they sign out:

```
this.store.find('user', fbRef.getAuth().uid).then(function(user) {
    user.destroyRecord();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question before. authAnonymously() will persist the session for as long as you’ve indicated in your Firebase Dashboard. Looks like this is an EmberFire issue. I’ll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: @Sara not a problem. I've actually since switched over to [fireplace](http://livsey.org/fireplace) as it better fits my needs and it seems to have no problems when re-using record IDs. Would still be interested to know if this is an actual issue in emberfire, or just a misuse of it on my part, if only just to satisfy my own curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

Each time you call `authAnonymously()`, it will create a new uid each time a new session is created. You can configure the session length in your Firebase Dashboard.

If you'd like to have users log in and out of your application, I'd recommend using Firebase's [email & password auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html) or authenticating with any of our [third-party providers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-providers).

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a little unclear about what my "sign out" process does, its not actually doing an `unauth()`, its just deleting the user that's associated with that uid at `/users/uid`. The only time I call `authAnonymously()` is when the app initially loads, and only if they do not already have an authenticated session (i.e. if they've never been to the app, have closed their browser, or the session expired).

Comment: Based on my testing so far, and what I've read in the docs, the uid is valid and persisted across page refreshes and multiple tabs, ect. for as long as the session length allows (I currently have it set to 30 days). I've verified this by authenticating via `authAnonymously()` once, and then console.logging `getAuth().uid`, which remains the same across page refreshes.

According the to the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/anonymous.html#section-logging-in), the only time the uid is not persisted is when `remember` is set to `never`.

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect before. The uid will be persisted for the length of the session. Looking into the error now.